# Only apply https redirection middleware based on a scoped service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, middleware

I have a web application that runs multiple websites. Based on a configuration loaded from the database, some sites must be redirected to HTTPS and some not. I would like to make use of the default HTTPSRedirection middleware, so have included it in my startup config as follows :

```
app.UseWhen(httpContext =>
{
    return app.Services.GetService<IContext>()!.IsForceHttps;
}, httpApp =>
{
    httpApp.UseHttpsRedirection();
});
```

The issue I am having now is that IContext is a scoped service and cannot be referenced at this point ( from the root context ).

I considered extending the HttpsRedirectionMiddleware class and then injecting IContext into the Invoke method, but then I got "multiple Invoke instances found" error on container startup.

So apart from basically rewriting the default HttpsRedirectionMiddleware ( don't want to do that ) is there any other way to achieve this?

P.S.: I would like to re-use this type of solution in other areas as well ( i.e. to activate the mini-profiler or to forward headers or to set SameOrigin etc.. )

Remember, this values will all be request/session specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I would post my solution here for any future reference. The trick was to resolve the scoped dependency using the provided httpContext ( as it is in essence scoped itself )

```
app.UseWhen(httpContext =>
{
    try
    {
        var context = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IContext>();
        return context!.ForceHttps;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "Failed to resolve logic for HTTPS redirection, defaulting to true");
        return true;
    }
            

 }, httpApp => { httpApp.UseHttpsRedirection(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea that I had when I read your question that I did not test in full or evaluate fully. Please test it and let me know if it solves your issue and does not introduce other issues.

Basically, instead of extending the middleware via inheritance, we will use composition. We will create a middleware that determines at runtime whether to call the wrapped middleware (e.g. Https Redirection) or to skip it.

```
public class ScopedService
{
    public bool UseMiddleware => true;
}

public class CustomMiddleware<TMiddleWare>
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    private readonly TMiddleWare wrappedMiddleware;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.next = next;

        wrappedMiddleware = ResolveMiddlewareWithCustomNext<TMiddleWare>(serviceProvider, next);
    }

    public static TMiddleware ResolveMiddlewareWithCustomNext<TMiddleware>(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var constructors = typeof(TMiddleware).GetConstructors();

        var constructor = constructors.First();

        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters()
            .Select(p =>
                p.ParameterType == typeof(RequestDelegate)
                    ? next
                    : serviceProvider.GetService(p.ParameterType))
            .ToArray();

        return (TMiddleware)constructor.Invoke(parameters);
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ScopedService service)
    {
        if (service.UseMiddleware)
        {
            //Invoke method may also be named InvokeAsync
            var invokeFunction =
                wrappedMiddleware.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            //You may need to resolve other parameters here (e.g. other scoped dependencies required by the wrapped middleware)
            var task = invokeFunction.Invoke(wrappedMiddleware, new object[] { httpContext}) as Task;

            await task;

            return;
        }

        await next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

`CustomMiddleware<TMiddleWare>` wraps the middleware (`TTMiddleWare`), it creates an instance of at construction passing the next parameter to it. When `CustomMiddleware<TMiddleWare>` is invoked, it used the `ScopedService` to determine whether to use the middleware or to call the next function directly.

Please note that this is a POC and you may need to adjust it to make it more generic.

You can use this custom middleware like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware<HttpsRedirectionMiddleware>>();
```